# Java/Scala ThreadPool: How to release a thread while waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, scheduling

Normally when a task is submitted to a thread pool (let's say a Fork-Join pool), it occupies the thread on which it runs until it completes. So if the task has to wait, for example for a `Future` to complete, it will keep the thread. This can be undesirable if many such tasks are waiting; then, many threads are put on hold. Not only this consumes a lot of memory, but  at the worst, you may reach the limit and cannot create any new threads any more leading to a deadlock (for example, on my macbook, I cannot create more than a few thousand threads in JVM).

One may argue that the problem can be solved by changing my program to avoid this scenario but very likely it comes at the cost of my program being less readable and more lengthy.

---

My question is if it is possible in some way to implement a method `release` that *releases the thread* such that the thread can be used to pick up another task from the queue, and schedule the rest of the method as a new task? 
So I was hoping to do this maybe using reflection, but could not find out how.

**Assumptions**
In my case, you can assume only `Runnable`s (therefore no return value). Also no call stack to worry about, i.e., the releasing happens directly in the method that constitutes the task submitted to the thread pool.

A simplistic usage would be like this:

```
// some code
while (! future.isDone()){
   return;
}
// continue with the logic
```

Answer (score 0):

Java threads map one to one to native threads and what you ask is not possible. Effectively you are asking for something like continuations or green threads/coroutines. There are some limitations to such approaches and they are currently not very popular. One example that exists on JVM is Kotlin [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html).

In pure Java you can make that part of code asynchronous and use `CompletableFuture.thenAccept` or other composable methods to schedule further processing after original future completes. Similar to that Scala has even richer library of futures and promises. Another possibility is to split your logic and submit parts of code as tasks to an `Executor` instance.

Comment: Indeed it is like continuations. Let me check Kotlin and see how that could solve my issue.